# Left joining in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am building my app and I needed to use `leftJoin` in laravel

I prepared a query in database and it works fine.

```
SELECT sp.id, ssp.sale_id, ssp.product_id FROM store_products sp 
LEFT JOIN store_sale_products ssp ON sp.id = ssp.product_id 
WHERE ssp.sale_id IS NULL AND sp.store_id = 1
```

Now I am implementing this query on laravel and I tried this

```
$nosaleproducts = Store_product::leftJoin('store_sale_products','store_products.id','=','store_sale_products.product_id')
        ->where('store_sale_products.sale_id','IS','NULL')
        ->where('store_products.store_id','=',session::get('store_id'))
        ->get(['store_products.id','store_products.product_name']);
```

But this gets me no results. Can anyone specify what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$nosaleproducts = Store_product::leftJoin('store_sale_products',function($join){
         $join->on('store_products.id','=','store_sale_products.product_id');})
        ->whereNull('store_sale_products.sale_id')
        ->where('store_products.store_id','=',session::get('store_id'))
        ->get(['store_products.id','store_products.product_name']);
```